# Ajax returns undefined response in node js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am trying to post a ajax request to my server.js script in node js. The script then passes the data from the ajax request to the stored procedure and is supposed to return the result to the ajax function. But for some reason, I am getting an undefined error while debugging my ajax function. What could I be doing wrong?

plain.ejs

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="container1" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
<div id ="container2" style="height:20px;"></div>
<div id ="container3" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">



     $(document).ready(function () {
            var bankid = [ 57, 9912, 9905, 16, 58 ];
            var country = ["KENYA", "KENYA", "KENYA", "UGANDA", "UGANDA"];
            var counter = 0;
            var merchantname = [];
            var successtranscs = [];
            var failedtranscs = [];
            var servicetranscs = [];
            var bankname;
            var rows =<%-JSON.stringify(Resultset)%>

                function initfunc() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "/dashboard",
                        data: JSON.stringify({country: country[counter], bankid: bankid[counter]}),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (Result) {
                            Result = Result.d;
                            console.log("result" +Result);
                            var data = [];
                            var merchantname = [];
                            var successtranscs = [];
                            var failedtranscs = [];
                            var servicetranscs = [];
                            var bankname;

                            for (var i in Result) {
                                merchantname.push(Result[i].merchant_name);
                                successtranscs.push(Result[i].success_transcs);
                                failedtranscs.push(Result[i].failed_transcs);
                                servicetranscs.push(Result[i].service_transcs);
                                bankname = Result[i].bankname;


                            }
                            StackedChart(bankname, merchantname, successtranscs, failedtranscs, servicetranscs);
                            merchantname = [];
                            successtranscs = [];
                            failedtranscs = [];
                            servicetranscs = [];
                            if (counter == country.length - 1) {
                                counter = -1;
                                counter++;
                            }
                            else {
                                counter++;
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (Result) {
                            console.log(Result.d);
                        }
                    });


            }
            initfunc();
            function callfunc() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "/dashboard",
                    data: JSON.stringify({country: country[counter], bankid: bankid[counter]}),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (Result) {
                        Result = Result.d;
                        console.log("result" +Result);
                        var data = [];
                        var merchantname = [];
                        var successtranscs = [];
                        var failedtranscs = [];
                        var servicetranscs = [];
                        var bankname;

                        for (var i in Result) {
                            merchantname.push(Result[i].merchant_name);
                            successtranscs.push(Result[i].success_transcs);
                            failedtranscs.push(Result[i].failed_transcs);
                            servicetranscs.push(Result[i].service_transcs);
                            bankname = Result[i].bankname;


                        }
                        StackedChart(bankname, merchantname, successtranscs, failedtranscs, servicetranscs);
                        merchantname = [];
                        successtranscs = [];
                        failedtranscs = [];
                        servicetranscs = [];
                        if (counter == country.length - 1) {
                            counter = -1;
                            counter++;
                        }
                        else {
                            counter++;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (Result) {


 console.log(Result.d);//it keeps going to the error //function

                    }
                });


            }




            function StackedChart(bank_name,merch_name, succ_val, fail_val, ser_val) {

                var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container1', {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: bank_name
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: merch_name
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        title: {
                            text: 'TransactionStatus'
                        },
                        stackLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            style: {
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        align: 'right',
                        x: -30,
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        y: 25,
                        floating: true,
                        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                        borderColor: '#CCC',
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        shadow: false
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                        pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        column: {
                            stacking: 'normal',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Servicefailure',
                        data: ser_val
                    }, {
                        name: 'Failure',
                        data: fail_val
                    }, {
                        name: 'Success',
                        data: succ_val
                    }]
                });
            }




            setInterval(callfunc, 2000);
        });



</script>


</body>
</html>
```

server.js -

```
var express = require('express');
var cnn = require('./DbConnection.js');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('highcharts');
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); //
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
dirname = "C:/Users/user/WebstormProjects/untitled/public";

require("jsdom").env("", function(err, window) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    var $ = require("jquery")(window);
});
app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});



app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var obj;

    cnn.TransactionInfo("KENYA","57", function (err, result) {
        // process result here
         console.log(result.length);
        var resultset = {"Result":result};
       obj = { "title":"fruit consumption", "name":"fruit eaten"};

        res.render("plain.ejs",{Resultset:resultset});

    });



});
app.post('/dashboard', function (req, res) {
    cnn.TransactionInfo(req.body.country,req.body.bankid, function (err, result) {

        var resultset = {"Result":result};


        res.render("plain.ejs",{Resultset:resultset});

    });
});
```

Comment: Which line does this error occur?

Comment: @C0dekid:-   error: function (Result) {


 console.log(Result.d);//it keeps going to the error //function

                    }

Comment: Try logging `Result` in the error handler, instead of `Result.d`. Also check your browser's console.

Answer (score 0):

By specifying `dataType : "json"`, you're telling jQuery that it should expect JSON data to be returned by the server. However, your Express handler is sending back HTML:

```
res.render("plain.ejs",{Resultset:resultset});
```

So the error will likely be that jQuery couldn't decode the response.

Try sending back a JSON response:

```
res.json({ Resultset : resultset });
```

Comment: :- Thank you but for some reason, it goes to the success function and returns Result.d as undefined.

Comment: @jessica I don't see a `d` property being defined anywhere, so that would make sense. Try using `Result` instead.

Comment: @robertklep- Thanks. Tried it but still doesn't work. This is what I get in the console - result : = result[object Object]

Comment: @robertklep- That's what I get after consoling the result.

Comment: @jessica that's to be expected, as you are stringifying the response. Try this: `console.log("result:", Result)` (use a comma, not a + sign)

Comment: I can see the data in the result now, But I wonder why I see blank graph with no data in it.

Comment: This is what I get in the console - Object
Resultset
:
Object
Result
:
Array[4]
0
:
Object
BankName
:
"FinanceTrust"
MERCHANTNAME
:
"AirtelMoney"
NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS
:
0
NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS
:
0
NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS
:
5
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
BankName
:
"FinanceTrust"
MERCHANTNAME
:
"Airtel Money"
NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS
:
0
NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS
:
0
NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS
:
3
__proto__
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object

Comment: @jessica perhaps using `Result = Result.Resultset` will fix that.

Comment: @robertklep- Still doesn't display anything. This is what I get when I console Result =  Result.Resultset -     ult 
Object
Result
:
Array[8]
0
:
Object
BankName
:
"IM BANK"
MERCHANTNAME
:
"MPesa"
NO_OF_FAILED_BANK_TRANSACTIONS
:
0
NO_OF_FAILED_SERVICE_TRANSACTIONS
:
7
NO_OF_SUCCESSFUL_TRANSACTIONS
:
32
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
Object
length
:
8

Comment: @jessica I'm inclined to suggest that you create a new question for this, as it's not really related to the original anymore.